# how many times does a string repeat itself - python?

Tags: python

I have strings in python like 'abcabcabc', 'abcdbabcdb'. How do I return the number of times a substring repeats itself within a string?

You want to find the longest substring in a string and return the occurrences. 
The first one would return 3, and the second one would return 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You can find the repeating strings using a regular expression with back-references. If you use `re.findall()`, the length of the result will be the number of repetitions.

Comment: To clarify, `'abc'` and `'abcdb'` are the respective substrings, right? Cause `'a'`/`'b'`/`'c'` are also feasible for the first, and `'a'`/`'c'`/`'d'` for the second.

Comment: I wanted it for any string, so the substring for 'abcdbabcdb' should be 'abcdb' which is in there twice

Comment: You say your code doesn't work completely. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I just had to return 1 instead of 0. Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the repetition of a substring can be partial at the end of the original string (i.e. the length of the substring is not necessarily an integer divisor of the length of the string), you could do it like this:

```
def maxRep(s):
 return len(s)/next(i for i in range(1,len(s)+1) if (s[:i]*len(s)).startswith(s))
```

output:

```
s = 'abcabcabc'
r = maxRep(s)
print(s,r) # 3.0

s = 'abcdbabcdb'
r = maxRep(s)
print(s,r) # 2.0

s = 'abcdbabcdbab'
r = maxRep(s)
print(s,r) # 2.4
```

*The function uses a brute force approach where every possible length of repeating substring is attempted to see if the result matches the string. The smallest substring length is used (i.e. the first length that matches) because this will give the greatest number of repetitions.*

if you need the substring to be completely repeated (i.e. no partial substring at the end, you can adjust the function like this:

```
def maxRep(s):
    return len(s)//next(i for i in range(1,len(s)+1) if not any(s.split(s[:i])))
```

*The condition is based on the fact that splitting the string using the a perfectly repeated substring will only produce empty values in the resulting list*

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find the greatest string that repeat itself:

```py
import re

a = 'abcabcabc'
regex = r'(\w+)(?:.*\1)+'
# greatest must contains: 'abc'
greatest = re.findall(regex, a)[0]
```

Now you can count the number of occurence:

```py
a.count(greatest)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
def repeat_finder(string):
    for i in range(len(string)//2,0,-1):
        if len(string)%i==0:
            n = len(string)//i
            if string == string[:i]*n:
                return (string[:i],n)
    return 'Not a repeat string.'

repeat_finder('abababab')
repeat_finder('sdlkfkfkfkffdd')
repeat_finder('ababababab')
```